# Create report from multiple excel files which are added automatically to the folder with different file names

Tags: excel, vba, synchronization, spreadsheet

**I would like to know if this is possible so please don't see this as a "create my project for me" post**

We are sending usage reports to our customers once a quarter (every 90 days from the date they bought the license). This report contains major tables with 30+ columns of raw number data.

I want to create a simple >drag new report into folder >paste results of main workbook into report

Creating a this is obviously simple but I want to:

1. Download the usage report (the filename represents the client
   name)
2. Store all these reports in a single folder
3. Have the core workbook detect new file
4. Core workbook reads the new excel file, adds the data to a new sheet on the core workbook
5. Delete the workbook (the new usage report dragged into the folder) after the data has been added
6. Core workbook creates appropriate content (graphs etc) from the
   new data

Are 3, 4, and 5 possible with VBA? I am not familiar with it at all and only recently discovered the possibility of macros in excel.

Comment: Yes, they are possible with VBA.

Comment: If you are deleting the files once they have been processed then you don't need to detect new files because you can simply process every file in the folder.

Comment: That is true. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I have a macro which opens all workbooks in a folder one by one, you'll notice where I have commented out a section, here you can enter your code and perform an action on the given workbook. This will loop through each workbook in your folder until there isn't any left.

```
Sub ImportMacro()

'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them'
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Values in sheets'
Dim VolatilityPortfolio As String
Dim ColValue As String
VolatilityPortfolio = "VolatilityPortfolio"

'Optimize Macro Speed'
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User'
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel'
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")'
  myExtension = "*.xl??"

'Target Path with Ending Extention'
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder'
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook'
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
'-------------------- Below is the worksheet macro --------------------------'

'To open the currentworkbook
 Workbooks(myFile).activate


'---------------------------- Above is the worksheet macro ----------------------- '
'Save and Close Workbook as CSV'
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True


    'Get next file name'
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed'
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings'
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you! definitely going to try and implement this.